# Compiler Exception: 'Overload resolution ambiguity' despite use of elvis operator

Tags: kotlin, elvis-operator

The following snippet causes the compiler to throw an exception:

```
fun main(){
   var numberOfBooks = null
   var s = null
   val l: Int = if (s != null) s.length else -1
   println(l)
   numberOfBooks = numberOfBooks?.dec()?:0 // this should default to 0
   println(numberOfBooks)
}
```

Giving the exceptions

```
Unresolved reference: length
Type mismatch: inferred type is IntegerLiteralType[Int,Long,Byte,Short] but Nothing? was expected
Type mismatch: inferred type is IntegerLiteralType[Int,Long,Byte,Short] but Nothing? was expected
Overload resolution ambiguity: public inline operator fun BigDecimal.dec(): BigDecimal defined in kotlin public inline operator fun BigInteger.dec(): BigInteger defined in kotlin
```

I thought the elvis operator would handle `null`. Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: Elvis is working. Your compiler complains, because it cannot decide how to resolve `.dec`, because there are multiple signatures matching.

Comment: Also: Beyond that, the compiler can't resolve `length` of the variable `s`, because no type is known for `s`.

Answer (score 4):

What types should Kotlin assign to `numberOfBooks` and `s` since you didn't provide any type? The solution is to explicitely define the types of your `null` variables:

```kotlin
fun main(){
  var numberOfBooks: Int? = null
  var s: String? = null
  val l: Int = if (s != null) s.length else -1
  println(l)
  numberOfBooks = numberOfBooks?.dec()?:0
  println(numberOfBooks)
}
```

Comment: Maybe to explain OPs original problem: The signatures of both `BigDecimal.dec` and `BigInteger.dec` are possible matches.

Comment: @TreffnonX I wonder why only those two `dec` operators are mentioned. There are many other `dec` operators that could match, like `Int.dec`, right?

Comment: @Sweeper Possibly the first ones the compiler encountered? Or the only ones defaultable by an integer literal? I truly can't say, though I wonder too.

Comment: I think it's something related to `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` [having some extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/#extensions-for-external-classes), probably the compiler gets confused.